# Generate Private key from seed

Tags: javascript, cryptography, rsa, blockchain, bitcoin

Is there any way to generate a private key and public key from a string like a user's password?
I want to retrieve it every time the user enters password

I use this elliptic but it randomly generates a keyPair

```
const EC = require('elliptic').ec;
const ec = new EC('secp256k1');
let keyPair = ec.genKeyPair();
```

Comment: seems like you really want is very weak encryption in that case

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: Don't create [brain wallets:](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Brainwallet)  especially low entropy human generated ones.

You can generate any 32-byte value (technically valid private keys on secp256k1 curve must be between `0x1 to 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE BAAE DCE6 AF48 A03B BFD2 5E8C D036 4140`) see [Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key#Range_of_valid_ECDSA_private_keys)

One way to do this is to hash the string you want to generate the key from:

```
const EC = require('elliptic').ec;
var crypto = require('crypto');

const ec = new EC('secp256k1');
let secret = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('password').digest('hex');
let keyPair = ec.keyFromSecret(secret);
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a JSON like this: {public_key: XXXX (String) , private_key: yyyy(String)}

Comment: Is there a way of doing this with a native `crypto` function? i.e. not using `elliptic`

Comment: should be able to. Instead of `ec.keyFromSecret`, try `setPrivateKey` and `getPublicKey`, of course using `createECDH('secp256k1');` to create the key exchange object. See example here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_ecdh_setpublickey_publickey_encoding

Comment: @JBaczuk I think your code is not right, because there is no `ec.keyFromSecret(...);` method

Comment: @Shruggie, the crypto lib doesn't include elliptic curves operations, neither base 58 conversions, so in order to get a valid key in a common format (WIF), as well as the matching public key, you will need to recode those two.

Comment: @SinaMirshafiei keyFromSecret is in the README: https://www.npmjs.com/package/elliptic